# Don't know how to sort a string of words ascending in assembly

Tags: string, sorting, assembly, ascii, x86-16

I have a string of 4 words (all with minimum 1 character and maximum 4 characters) and i need to sort them (i.e {‘1234’, ‘abcd’, ‘123’, ‘e’} and after sort we will have {‘e’, ‘123’, ‘1234’, ‘abcd’}). I need to sort them by their ascii code.

My Code ( the bubble sort part is incomplete)

```
    DOSSEG
    .MODEL SMALL
    .STACK 32
    .DATA
NUMERE  DB  0Dh,0Ah,'Nr.(1)=$'
KBD DB  5,0,0,0,0,0,0
STORE   DB 4 DUP (20h,20h,20h,20h)
    .CODE
START: MOV AX,@DATA
    MOV DS, AX
    MOV CX, 4
    MOV DI, (OFFSET STORE) + 4
AGAIN: PUSH CX ; afisare sir de interogare
    MOV DX, OFFSET NUMERE
    MOV AH, 9
    INT 21h
    INC [NUMERE+6]
    MOV [KBD+1], 0 ; se citeste un numar cu max. 4 cifre
    MOV AH, 0Ah
    MOV DX, OFFSET KBD
    INT 21h
    MOV CL, [KBD+1]
    MOV CH, 0
    MOV SI, (OFFSET KBD) + 2
    PUSH DI
    SUB DI, CX
NEXT: MOV AL, [SI]
    MOV [DI], AL
    INC SI
    INC DI
    LOOP NEXT
    POP DI
    ADD DI, 4
    POP CX
    LOOP AGAIN
;bubble sort starts
MOV CX, 3
SORT:           
    PUSH CX
    MOV CX,3
    MOV SI, OFFSET STORE
    MOV DI, OFFSET STORE+4
    INNER_LOOP:
        MOV AX, [DI]
        CMP [SI], AX
        JNG NO_SWAP
        SWAP: 
        NO_SWAP:
        INC SI
        INC DI
    LOOP INNER_LOOP
    INC SI
 POP CX
 LOOP SORT
;bubble sort ends

MOV SI, OFFSET STORE
MOV CX, 4
DISP: CALL CRLF 
    PUSH CX
    MOV CX,4
NUM:MOV AH, 2
    MOV DL, [SI]
    INT 21h
    INC SI
    LOOP NUM
    POP CX
    LOOP DISP
    MOV AH, 4CH
    INT 21H
CRLF:MOV AH,2
    MOV DL,0Ah
    INT 21h
    MOV AH,2
    MOV DL,0Dh
    INT 21h
    RET
END START
```

I tried multiple methods but i don't know how to do this in assembly, so please help me

Comment: Instead of cluttering the source with loading the input from keyboard, begin with static definition of input array, e.g.  `Array: DD ‘1234’, ‘abcd’, ‘123’, ‘e’`, and watch your bubble-sort algorithm in debugger.

Comment: There's missing code for swapping.